# Website blocks PHP CURL calls from my webhosting and localhost, but not from other hosting

Tags: php, curl

I have this PHP script running on a webhost that uses CURL to connect to a webpage:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://crewlink.someairline.com/crewlink/clApp?parameters=parameters');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Dnt: 1';
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

// do some stuff with $result;

curl_close($ch);
```

Since a few days the connection gets redirected to a page that says "Our website protection system has detected unexpected behavior from your network, therefore we ask you to verify that you are not a robot." So I did some testing and I found that running the PHP script from my localhost (XAMPP) results in the same redirection, but running it from a different web host, the script is successful and returns what it's expected to.
If I ssh into my web hosting machine and run the same script from the terminal I still get redirected:

```
curl 'https://crewlink.someairline.com/crewlink/clApp?parameters=parameters' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
```

But not if I run it from my personal machine (which is also my localhost) or if I run it from an AWS EC2 instance.

I tried also setting a verified active proxy in the PHP script, thinking the redirection could be based on IP detection with:

```
$proxy = "http://45.76.222.170:8080/";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

But still on my web host and localhost I get redirected, on the other web host I don't.
Could someone help me understand what I could do to make it work, and most of all why do I get redirected when CURL runs from a PHP script but not when run from terminal from my same machine?

Comment: In order to verify that an IP block list is not in use, you'll have to also use the same proxy from a host where you have experienced success. One obvious possibility is that the proxy is also on the blocked list. IP blocking is SOP when robots are detected

Comment: @PaulKeister Sorry, I forgot to specify it: I have tried using the same proxy also on the web host where the PHP script was successful just to make sure they are not blocking proxies and it worked like a charm, even if it was obviously slower